Understanding proof of Hall's graph theorem
I am struggling with understanding proof of Halls theorem.

Theorem: Let $G=(V_1\cup V_2,E)$ be a bipartite graph and for each $U\subseteq V_1$ let $$N_{G}(U)=\{v\in V_2\ :\ \exists u\in U\text{ such that}\{u,v\}\in E\}$$
Then, $G$ has a matching of size $|V_1|$ if and only if $|N_{G}(U)|\geq|U|$ for all $U\subseteq V_1$

I am struggling with the induction proof from my lectures, here is the part of it that I do not understand:

First Case: there is a set $A \in V_1, A \neq V_1$ such that $|A| = N_{G}(A)$

Let's define: $B = N_{G}(A)$
$A' = V_1 \setminus A$
$B' = V_2 \setminus B$
$G_1 = G(A \cup B)$
$G_2 = G(A' \cup B')$
Then we are checking Hall's condition for $G_2$ graph and for $A'$: let's take $U \in A'$, then: $|U| + |A| = |U \cup A| \le |N_{G}(U \cup A)| = |N_{G_2}(U) \cup B| = |N_{G_2}(U)| + |B| = |N_{G_2}(U)| + |A|$
But I am completely unable to understand the following:

$|N_{G}(U \cup A)| = |N_{G_2}(U) \cup B|$

$|N_{G_2}(U) \cup B| = |N_{G_2}(U)| + |B|$


Please, explain it to me. I've been trying to understand it for almost 2 hours already and it's really demotivating

It may make it easier to remember that $B$ is $N_{G_1}(A)$.
Also remember that $G_1$ and $G_2$ are vertex disjoint graphs.
For (1), we can add an intermediate step, $|N_G(U\cup A)|  = |N_G(U)\cup N_G(A)| = |N_G(U)\cup B|$. Now $N_G(U)$ might contain some vertices from $B$, but we aren't going to double count these in the union, so we can replace $N_G(U)$ with $N_{G_2}(U)$ without changing the size of the union.
(2) follows from the fact that $N_{G_2}(U)$ and $B = N_{G_1}(A)$ are disjoint sets.

why in (2) can we say that they are disjoint?

$G_1$ and $G_2$ are vertex disjoint by definition
